# how to append an object to a URL

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I need to be able to append an encoded object to a URI to pass it to a Web API endpoint.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35773793/117700) post, the author is creating an object:

```
var request = new Object();
request.SearchWindowStart = start.toISOString();
request.SearchWindowEnd = end.toISOString();
request.ServiceId = "5f3b6e7f-48c0-e511-80d7-d89d67631c44";
request.Direction = '0';
request.NumberOfResults = 10;
request.UserTimeZoneCode = 1;
```

Then they are appending it to a URL:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest()
req.open("GET", clientUrl + "/api/data/v8.0/Search(AppointmentRequest=@request)?@request=" + JSON.stringify(request) , true);
```

**I actually cannot modify the C sharp code however I have two options. The first option is to add the parameters into the URL I actually cannot modify the c# code however I have two options. The first option is to add the parameters into the URL and the other option would be to add a body to the request with my intended object.**

If I know the structure of the object ahead of time how do I include it with my request?

Comment: You shouldn't be sending data through a URL like that, you should be passing it as the body of a REST request...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i use JSON.Stringify in code-behind of an ASP.Net project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343342/can-i-use-json-stringify-in-code-behind-of-an-asp-net-project)

Comment: @maccettura example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code snippet you need to serialize the object to JSON. You can use Json.Net as already linked in the other answer.

Using OP as an example...

```
var request = new {
    SearchWindowStart = "some_start_value",
    SearchWindowEnd = "some_end_value",
    ServiceId = "5f3b6e7f-48c0-e511-80d7-d89d67631c44",
    Direction = '0',
    NumberOfResults = 10,
    UserTimeZoneCode = 1
};
//JSON.stringify(request)
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
var url = clientUrl + "/api/data/v8.0/Search(AppointmentRequest=@request)?@request=" + json;
```

From there you should be able to use the URL as desired.

Comment: Interesting you're saying that I can use an anonymous type?

Comment: Doesn't really matter as you have the object just to serialize it to JSON. If you already have your own types you can serialize those the same way.

Comment: I have only two options. I can either change the url and add parameters to it or I can add a body to the request. I actually cannot modify the C sharp code.

Comment: You can only add a body to POST or PUT request. All other request types ignore the body.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a two ways.

1. Just add every propery of the object with the value to the url eg. /search?property1=value1&property2=value2 
   Of course each value should be url encoded.
2. Serialize the whole object into json and send it via post or get. Look at the https://www.newtonsoft.com/json how to do it. Sending request could be done by simple WebClient class.

Answer (score 0):

```
let encodedObj = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(yourObject))
```

Then you could just.

```
req.open("GET", clientUrl +  
 "/api/data/v8.0/Search(AppointmentRequest=@request)?@request=" + encodedObj, true);
```

Although according to: https://javascript.info/url
The encode functions are based on the obsolete version RFC2396, and advises you to use these classes instead:
URL and URLSearchParams to build a URL.